# Match four consecutive cells to another four consecutive cells

Tags: google-sheets, compare, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets inside a Google Sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2. There are four columns (A:D) side by side in each sheet:

```
Column A: File Number,
Column B: Land,
Column C: Ocean,
Column D: Air,
```

If the four columns in Sheet1 match the four columns in Sheet2 (A:D='Sheet2!A:D) then I want the value "CANCELLED" to appear in Column E in Sheet1.

For example, if A1:D1 in Sheet1 matches A1:D1 in Sheet2 then I want the text "CANCELLED" to appear in E1 in Sheet1.

Comment: What iIf A1:D1 in Sheet1 Matches A2:D2 in Sheet2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear on whether you re looking for a row-to-row match or if the values in A1:D1 can match A:D in any row on the second sheet.

```
'scenario 1 - row-to-row
'if(a1&b1&c1&d1=sheet2!a1&sheet2!b1&sheet2!c1&sheet2!d1, "CANCELLED", text(,))

'scenario 2 - a1:d1 match anywhere in sheet2!a:d
=if(countifs(sheet2!a:a, a1, sheet2!b:b, b1, sheet2!c:c, c1, sheet2!d:d, d1), "CANCELLED", text(,))

'scenario 3 - a1:d1 match anywhere in sheet2!a:d including blanks-to-blanks
=if(countifs(sheet2!a:a, if(len(a1), a1, "<>"), sheet2!b:b, if(len(b1), b1, "<>"), sheet2!c:c, if(len(c1), c1, "<>"), sheet2!d:d, if(len(d1), d1, "<>")), "CANCELLED", text(,))
```

Comment: I was looking for scenario 2. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there a way to match blank Cells ? This formula only works if there are no blank cells

Comment: Yes, `"<>"` is the same as count blank. You can add conditions for each A1:D1 so if it is blank, it looks for blanks.